# SceneKit applyForce on SCNNode not working

Tags: physics, scenekit

I'm trying to use the `applyForce` method of SceneKit on a SCNNode.   The application is detecting when a specific node is touched via the touch screen, and it is supposed to apply a force on the node; however, the SCNNode does not move.   I've properly set the physics to `dynamic` on the SCNNode, and it responds to gravity.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    ...

    // retrieve the floor node
    let floorNode = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/floor.dae")
    floorNode?.rootNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z:-10)
    floorNode?.rootNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: nil)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode!.rootNode)

    let treeNode = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/tree.dae")
    treeNode?.rootNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z:-10)
    treeNode?.rootNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(treeNode!.rootNode)

    ...

}

func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    ...

    // check what nodes are tapped
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    // check that we clicked on at least one object
    if hitResults.count > 0 {

        print("A hit!")

        // retrieved the first clicked object
        let result: AnyObject = hitResults[0]

        result.node.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(x:10000,y:1,z:1), asImpulse: true)
        result.node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x:0,y:1,z:0, w:100.0), asImpulse: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to apply the force onto a child node (which the hit test returns), when I should have applied the force to the child node's parent.

I am importing SCNScenes via .DAE (Collada) files, and the rootNode of the SCNScene is not the model itself, but the parent of the model.